# Customize errors symfony

Tags: forms, symfony1, customization

There are some "best practice" in Symfony to customize form errors?
For exemple, if i would to show "Campo obligatorio" when the field is required.

1)How can i do that better way and independent from what forms call it?
2)How can i customize message 'An object with the same "%namefield" already exist.' ?

Thanks

**updated**

sorry, but if i try to do 'invalid' how you said me... it print me the same error

```
$this->setValidator('urlres', new sfValidatorString(array(
                          'min_length' => 6,
                        ), array(
                          'min_length' => 'URL must be longer',
                          'required'   => 'Required field',
                          'invalid' => 'URL exist'
                        )));
```

prints me:
    *  An object with the same "urlres" already exist.

**updated**
Felix, your solution is fantastic but it prints me this error:
"urlres: that url already exists"

Are there some way to delete "field:" ??

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe [this form post](http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/t/23467/) helps you:

Put the code

```
sfValidatorBase::setDefaultMessage('required', 'Field required');
```

in the "configure" of you application configuration `apps/youApp/config/yourAppConfiguration.class.php`.

You should be able to set the default value for every error message type this way.

---

If you want to set certain error messages for certain fields, think about to create a form class that defines all this and let all other forms inherit from this one.
The subclasses then only specify which fields should be displayed (and maybe custom validation logic).

You can find an example how to do this in the [Admin Generator chapter](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12#chapter_12_sub_class) of the symfony book.

This is the cleanest approach IMHO.

---

**Edit:**

If you want leave fields blank, you have to add the `required => false` option:

```
  'email'   => new sfValidatorEmail(array('required' => false))
```

Regarding the error message: This sounds like the `urlres` is marked as unique in the database table and the value already exists. Maybe you should check the database schema definition.

---

**Edit 2:**

To test both, length and uniqueness, you should use [`sfValidatorAnd`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfValidatorAnd) and `sfValidatorDoctrineUnique`:

```
$this->setValidator('urlres', new sfValidatorAnd(
                    array(
                      new sfValidatorString(
                            array( 'min_length' => 6, ), 
                            array( 'required' => 'Required field',
                                   'min_length' => 'URL must be at least %min_length% chars long.' )
                      ),
                      new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(
                            array( 'model' => 'yourModel', 
                                   'column' => 'theColumn', 
                                   'primary_key' => 'thePrimaryKeyColumn',
                                   'throw_global_error' => false),
                            array('invalid' => "That URL already exists")
                      )
                    ));
```

Also your use of the `invalid` error code in the string validator is not correct. You set the invalid message to 
`URL exists` *but how can a **string** validator know this*? It only checks whether the given string meets the `min_length`, `max_length` criteria or not.

Btw I assumed that you use Doctrine but I think the same validators are available for Propel.

---

**Edit 3:**
Set the option `'throw_global_error' => false`. But I am not sure if that works.

You can also have a look at the [source code](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.2/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/validator/sfValidatorDoctrineUnique.class.php) if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Felix, it works fine and it is a clean method to do what i want.
Can u help me with the "An object with the same "urlres" already exist." error? what error type must i catch to customize this error message?

thanks a lot.

Comment: And another question... is possible to validate a field only if it is filled? In my form i could fill email address or phone number... but to validate email adress i need to assign a sfValidatorEmail to email field...if i do that,they raise an 'invalid' error...

Comment: yes felix, is unique. so i have to read before insert to show a custom error?
thanks

Comment: thanks felix, it works fine :)
it prints me this error "urlres: that url already exists", therer are some way to only show the error message without field..?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you.
You can easily customize standard form errors in `configure` method of your form class. Here is an example:
1)

```
<?php
   class myForm extends BaseMyForm
      public function configure(){
         parent::configure();
         $this->setValidator(
            'my_field' => new sfValidatorString(
               array('min_length'=>3, 'max_length'=>32, 'required'=>true),
               array('required' => 'Hey, this field is required!')
            )
         );
      }
```

2) Just change a message that has a code 'invalid'.

All you need is just find a valid message code to customize particular default messages. More info - [Symfony Forms in Action: Chapter 2 - Form Validation](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/02-Form-Validation)

**Updated:**

And if you don't want to customize error messages in all your form classes, just create your own base validator class:

```
abstract class myBaseValidator extends sfValidatorBase
```

and there redefine default 'required' and 'invalid' messages.

Comment: DArmen, thanks but what i try to say is... probabily in a project you have more than one form from the same entity/object or probabily in all entities/objects you want to show message 'you must enter field'. Is this possible to write 'default errors' in only one place?
I will try 'invalid' error and hope that works :)

thanks Darmen.

Comment: I see in another projects that they create a class and inside they define text errors. This way they can do this, but... there are another way?

Comment: @Darmen: YOU ARE DOING IT WRONG - hardcoding detected

Comment: @Develop7, yes, I know, my bad. Just wanted to show schematically

Comment: Creating a custom base validator to set default `required`, `invalid` messages is really unnecessary (if not even wrong), as you can set the default with e.g. `sfValidatorBase::setDefaultMessage('required', 'Field required');`

Answer (score 0):

> Are there some way to delete "field:"
>   ??

Yes: `throw_global_error => true`