# Translating default form validation error messages in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony-1.4, message

I want to translate the default form validation messages in symfony, like
 'required' => 'my own text'
Is there a way to do this? I searched in google, but haven't find anything useful. The XLIFF files are not working for me. :(

OR

Is there a way, to set default validation messages for like 'required' fields?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can manipulate the default error messages globally but you can access the i18n Object where you want with these lines of code:

```
$i18n = sfContext::getInstance()->getI18N();
$i18n->__('your message');
```

Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This post can help you: [Customize errors symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086543/customize-errors-symfony/2096123#2096123)